# hide cck field not working

Tags: entities

I want to expose the node add form for a particular content type to anonymous users but not with all the fields visible. I want limited fields to be visible to anonymous user. 
I have tried to hide the unwanted fields through display fields functionality of cck module, but it does not seem to work.

I also want to theme the node add form in a way that the various text fields with different text sizes should all appear of the same size to anonymous user. Just as a proper form.

Please tell me a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should also have a look at the [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module, which allows you to control granular permissions per field by role.

By default, if a user can edit a node they can edit all fields, but Field Permissions allows you to create specific privileges for the field if you need more granular control.

So for this instance, you'd want to enable edit privileges for the fields you want to hide from the anonymous users, then go to user permissions and grant edit permissions for those fields only to authenticated users.  The result would be that the fields would be hidden from anonymous users, but still editable by authenticated users.

You could then use the Forms API as Dan described to make the fields all of a length for anonymous users, or use something as simple as CSS if your theme attaches a body attribute for logged-out users (many do).

Answer (score 0):

Two different ways to do this are through creating a custom form in a drupal through the form API or the webform module. Either way it requires that you save the values into an array and deliever them to a Drupal hook that creates the node you want.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I think you must be very correct. I am pretty new to drupal . I did this by hiding the unwanted fields. This is done through a custom module that uses hook node create. But I would love to try your method. The only difficulty is that i dont know how to collect the form field values in array and deliver them to drupal hook. Can you please elaborate upon this, preferably with exampled of code snippets.